# Which framework for browser plugin works for all browsers in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, browser, opera, firebreath

I am creating a browser plugin for Linux. It should support all the browsers - firefox, chrome, opera. I opted for firebreath, but it doesn't seem to support opera in Linux. Is there any better alternative!

Comment: Why do you make it a browser plugin, and what are the intended features and role of your plugin???

Comment: I want to create a plugin for browser integration of an external download manager. The browser plugin should prevent the default inbuilt download manager from downloading and should pass on download url to external download manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A browser plugin will not do what you want it to.  Browser plugins cannot "prevent the default [built-in] download manager from downloading" or "pass on download url to [an] external download manager".  Browser plugins are only aware of a single page and only when they are injected into said page with an object/embed tag or loaded to handle a document with a specific mimetype.

For more information on the differences see http://npapi.com/extensions

A quick google search for browser extension frameworks yields a couple of possibilities:

- http://kangoextensions.com/
- http://crossrider.com/

I don't know if they work on linux or not.

**NOTE:** Though a browser extension is what you need it is possible that the ultimate solution may involve a browser extension that makes use of a browser plugin, in which case [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) is probably your best bet.  I don't know of any reason why Opera on linux wouldn't work (though I've never before had anyone ask about it), you'd just have to figure out where opera expects with the plugins to be.  FireBreath creates [NPAPI plugins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) on linux and opera should support those.

Comment: It was mentioned in the website firebreath.org, that only chrome and firefox are supported for Linux. Anyways, if it supports Opera, then FireBreath is best. Besides, DAP, IDM and many other download managers achieve browser integration with opera by just using NPAPI plugin and no extension(addon). I can register all the mime-types related to different files with my plugin. So, browser would simply invoke the plugin for all file mime-types, and plugin in turn would invoke the download manager. Isn't that possible. This is actually my first NPAPI project, so i don't know much.

Comment: First of all, I wrote FireBreath, so you can trust what I say about what works.  We don't test it with opera, so it isn't supported, but that doesn't mean it can't work, just that you'll have to do your own hoofwork if something doesn't.  Secondly, unless all the filetypes you care about are types that nothing else will care about you're asking for trouble to try to just be a handler for all of those types.  Most NPAPI download managers just have a javascript interface for downloading files, they don't actually work automatically on all pages

Comment: So, what do you recommend finally. Should I use extension instead of plugin or just plugin would do, what if it might be trouble some.

Comment: that totally depends on what you need to do.  If you can get by with a javascript API to drive the download manager and not have it automatic, then use a plugin.  if you need it to be automatic, then build an extension. Please, for the love of all compiled code, do *not* attempt to register your plugin as the handler for all reasonable mimetypes just so you can be invoked to download them.  That would be a Bad Idea.